# Angular Cordova app goes blank when cordova.js is included

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap, angular8, cordova-ios

I am creating an Angular + Cordova application and it works great in the browser.

The issue what I am facing is that when I try to include `cordova.js` file, the app goes blank when loaded on a device. I have done some [research](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22509) and it turns out to be something with `cordova.exec` and `zone.js` used in Angular causing the issue.

I would like a solution on how to properly include `cordova.js` in an Angular based project.

**Cordova**

```
android 8.0.0
ios 5.0.1
```

**Angular**

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  8.1.1
@schematics/angular               8.1.1
@schematics/update                0.801.1
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.35.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:
This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiIGcmHtDDE&list=LLpv78mT2s6hT7TPl-aE4VCw&index=5&t=239s) says we need to change the `<base href="/">` in your index.html to `<base href="./">`. If that doesn't work, try changing your `type="module"` to `type="text/javascript"` in your index.html.

Comment: this is not the issue with base url. its with change detection

Comment: Okay, please let me know if you figure out how to correctly include cordova.js in your project as I am also working on a Cordova-Angular app

Comment: yep, the issue occurs only on iOS. have a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22509

Comment: Yes, thank you! I found a patch on your link (see https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/02/cordova-vs-zonejs-or-why-is-angulars-document-event-listener-not-in-a-zone.html) - although I guess you meant the issue only occurs in Android

Comment: Not really, the workaround did not work and the issue is actually only on iOS.